# convert unicode characters while data loading in uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unicode, uiwebview

```
{   disclaimertxt = "<b>sample tex\U221a\U00a9t n\U221a\U00a9ewerv\U221a\U00a9e iew adults.</b>
\n<br/>
\n<br/>
\nthis is sample \U221a\U2020 an d\U221a\U00a9convertion of the language\U221a\U00a9reduction\U201a\U00c4\U00b6
\n                    ";
}
```

the above one is dictionary which contains above value with key `disclaimertext`

but in output the unicode characters is replaced with `?(C)" and "?A`

and my code is :

```
NSData *messagedata = [dictionary[disclaimertxt] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:messagedata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

so i want to display those unicode characters with respected text/value while loading in uiwebview.. plz give ur suggestions. in ios7 its working fine with desired output what i need. but when i run ios6 aim getting above outout.so plz find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. manually load the `HTML` from the page that doesn't include the meta tag, into a string.
2. Using string manipulation, insert your appropriate encoding meta tag into the manually loaded `HTML`
3. set the `HTML` in your web view to the modified string using `loadHTMLString:`

Use this to convert Unicode charaters to `NSString`:

```
char cString[] = "This isn\u2019t Test String";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now use this string in your Webview.

Comment: can u please show with example..im not understand...actually that dictionary value is coming from web service.

Comment: but those dictionary value coming from web service.so i don't know how to change manually.but ur example is working fine.but how to change my above dictionary value  manually?

Comment: If your code is working & your problem is solved than ignore that manual part.